# Horizontal scrollable toolbar of Flutter quill package

Tags: flutter, quill

does anyone have the idea to implement a horizontal toolbar as package Flutter_quill said? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `multiRowsDisplay` to `false`. Something like the following:

```
var toolbar = QuillToolbar.basic(
  controller: _controller,
  multiRowsDisplay: false,
  showAlignmentButtons: true,
);
```